# Can't Refer to Controller Function ZF2

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework2

I tried to send post value to OrderController (I use ZF2). I have javascript code in view folder.These are the code:

```
function submitHandler(form) {
       var urls = '<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/order/saveOrder';
       var pack= $("#pack").val(),
           name= $("#name").val(),
           instit= $("#instit").val(),
           telp= $("#telp").val(),
           email= $("#email").val(),
           address= $("#address").val(),
           orderno = "test",
           order_stat ="phone",
           pack_type = "recurring",
           rec_period ="monthly"; 
         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: urls,
           data: {
               pack: pack,
               name: name,
               instit:instit,
               telp: telp,
               email: email,
               address: address,
               orderno : orderno,
               order_stat :order_stat,
               pack_type : pack_type,
               rec_period :rec_period
           },
           success: function(msg) {
               var result = JSON.parse(msg);          
               if (result.success) {        
                   alert("SUccESSSS");
               } else {
                   alert(result.msg);
               }           
           },
           error: function(xhr, status, error){
                alert("Failed");
           }
       }); 
    }
```

And these are code from controller:

```
 public function saveOrderAction() {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        /*
        $storage = Order\Storage::factory($this->getDb());
        $attd = new Order($storage);

        $success = false;
        $msg = '';

        $attd->orderno = $post['orderno'];
        $attd->order_stat = $post['order_stat'];
        $attd->pack = $post['pack'];
        $attd->pack_type = $post['pack_type'];
        $attd->rec_period = $post['rec_period'];
        $attd->name = $post['name'];
        $attd->instit = $post['instit'];
        $attd->telp = $post['telp'];
        $attd->email = $post['email'];
        $attd->address = $post['address'];
        //$save = $attd->saveOrder();
        if ($attd->saveOrder(true)) { */
            $success = true;
            $msg = 'Saved Success';
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert($msg);</script>";
            print_r('test');
            printf('test2');
        $response->setContent(json_encode(array("success" => $success, "msg" => $msg)));
        return $response;
    }
```

But it doesn't show anything. So I have commented and just want to show alert, but it doesn't show. Help me,thanks.

Comment: you should check first if there is an error in you controller action,

Comment: i tried to show alert in action but it can't. i don't know how to check it. @PrinceG

Comment: can you try `var_dump($post); exit;`

Comment: @PrinceG i tried but it still nothing.

Comment: Have you actually tried accessing the url you're having problems with in your browser to see if there's a problem with your controller? The step @PrinceG is suggesting would be best served by you visiting the url directly without the ajax call just to make sure it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change your URL to:

```
var urls = '<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/order/save-order';
```

URL's in zend are lowercase. Multiple words are seperated by dashes. When the request is processed the action is camelCased so your action methods are proper PSR-2.